# Function implicitly has return type 'any' error

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm calling the function but it throwing error in object : any(Function implicitly has return type 'any' error because it does not have a return type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in one of its return expressions.ts(7024))

```
let getValues = (object : any) => {
  return object && typeof object === "object"
    ? [
      ...("title" in object ? [object.title] : []),
      ...Object.values(object).flatMap(getValues)
    ]
  : [];
 };


getValues(courseProperties.parent.children[0]).map((title : any) => (
  <div>{title}</div>
))
```

Comment: `let getValues:(obj:any)=>any = xxx` try this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should give your `getValues` a return type, like so:

```
let getValues = (object : any): any[] => {
    return object && typeof object === "object"
        ?
            [
                ...("title" in object ? [object.title] : []),
                ...Object.values(object).flatMap(getValues)
            ]
        : [];
};
```

but preferablly:

```
let getValues = (object : any): unknown[] => {
    return object && typeof object === "object"
        ?
            [
                ...("title" in object ? [object.title] : []),
                ...Object.values(object).flatMap(getValues)
            ]
        : [];
};
```